# How to make jit work with collections module?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I tried optimizing my code by running it on GPU, but I encountered the following error. 

Also, I'm fairly new to this, so I have little idea how to work with numba decorators, and my aim for this is to speed up my program.

```
ValueError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'collections.defaultdict'>

@jit(target = "cuda")
def initialize(foreign_no_of_words,foreign_l,english_l,num_dict_dutch,num_dict_eng):
    probabilities = {} # Initializing proablities
    #count = {} # Count
    counter = 1
    index = -1*(foreign_no_of_words)

    num_dict_dutch = make_dict_dutch(foreign_l,num_dict_dutch)

    for i in english_l.keys():
        for j in foreign_l.keys():
            s = i+"_"+j
            probabilities[s] = 1/foreign_no_of_words

            #count[s] = 0

        index = write_to_file(probabilities,i,counter,PROB_FILE,foreign_no_of_words,index,num_dict_eng)
        #write_to_file(count,i,counter,COUNT_FILE)
        counter +=1
        probabilities ={}

    return True
```

The goal is to lessen the function running time.

Comment: Using this for IBM Model 1

Answer (score 1):

Numba does not support the entire python language, but instead is capable of jitting a (growing) subset of its features. Please see:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

Currently, numba only supports `namedtuples` from the `collections` module. Also please note that writing code for the GPU is even more restricted:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/index.html#cuda-index